# Cannot get proper json response from my simple nodejs server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

SERVER : cloud server, Ubuntu 15.04 x64. nginx is installed listening port 80.

SERVER program : written using NodeJS, simply response in json. like { msg : "done" }

Client (HTML page using React and JQuery) : simple ask the server for the json data.

The problem is on client

```js
// 1)
this.serverRequest = $.get({url:'https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists', success:function(ret) {
// 2)
//this.serverRequest = $.get({url:'http://my_server_ip_address:7534/test', success:function(ret) {
      alert("ok done");
    }.bind(this), error:function(e) {
      alert("Error : " + e);
    }.bind(this)});
```

I have no problem with 1) request. I do receive some data.
but with 2) request, 'error' function is called and executing 'alert('Error :' + e);' only shows 'Error : [object Object]'.  It does not show any useful information..

So I thought my nodejs server program has some problems and I went on searching for answers. I think I try all possible answers..

1) setting iptable to accept port 7534.
2) making nodejs server to listen on 0.0.0.0
3) using res.json().. res.jsonp()

I can see {msg : "done"} if I try with Chrome. so I guess my nodejs server works.

Comment: Is the interface using https? Do you see any errors in your JavaScript console (F12)?

Comment: First, you receive error message  `Error: [object Object ] ` because it's base types transformation in js. Second, in nginx maybe install firewall, but don't sure, such as you received right data in Chrome.  What browser you use when receive a wrong data

Comment: no it does use https. it uses http.

Comment: blex : no it does use **https**. it uses **http**.
There is no error shown in console.

Dmitry : all browsers receive the data correctly. I use Chrome to open my client html file which contains javascript codes.

Comment: `Error : [object Object]` because e is an object. And `{msg : "done"}` is not a json its an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the message of error. Instead of `alert(e)` use `console.log(e)`, for see properties of object e.

Comment: ah...man. why didn't i check the console in the first place.. (I didn't know how to check anyway)  Yes there is a comment. net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  hm...now I need to configure my server setting. I dont know how yet =P

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

ok following @Juven_v 's answer..I figured the 'object' was Error object. And I was able to see the error message through console.log(e).

Here is summary of the solution I found:
1) When the server program responses, put header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin with value *.

I am using nodeJS with express so the code is

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

And the client requests with the url.
I use JQuery and the code is

`$.get({
        url: "http://address!!!!",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("yay");
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    });`

If the above client code does not work, then try to add 'dataType: "json"'

2) If I add the following code in the server program..
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type');

then the client request must have
//contentType: "application/json",

References :
[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

[jQuery AJAX to node server throws net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731799/jquery-ajax-to-node-server-throws-neterr-connection-refused)

[net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error jQuery ajax node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712523/neterr-connection-refused-error-jquery-ajax-node-js)

THANK YOU ALL!!!!